# VPN подключение в Ubuntu (через консоль)

Tags: vpn, ubuntu, linux

Что делал: 0) Ctrl+Alt+1 1)    sudo apt-get install pptp-linuxговорит, что у меня самая новая версия(естественно, по английски);2)    sudo nano /etc/ppp/chap-secretsВ этом файле:    # Secrets for authentication using CHAP    # client server secret IP addresses    login * passwd *Где Login - мой логин а passwd - пароль3)    sudo nano /etc/ppp/peers/vpn_connectтам:    pty "pptp ppp.ultranet.ru --nolaunchpppd"    name login    remotename ultra    lock    noauth    defaultroute    nobsdcomp    nodeflateГде login - мой логин (ppp.ultranet.ru сначала не менял, затем сменил на IP адрес шлюза - результат одинаков)5)    sudo pon vpn_connectзатем:    ifconfigНо там есть только eth0 и lo. ppp0 нету6)    sudo pon vpn_connect debug logfd 2 nodetachвыдаёт - смотри снимок.-----------------------Стоить добавить, что в линуксе я очень-очень слаб. У меня не совсем ubuntu, а XBMCbuntuвсе, что я делал, было по 95[инструкции][1]95 провайдера. И немножко в помощь яндекс для адаптации сего под убунту. Зачем всё это надо? Хотелось бы иметь интернет на медиацентре. Заранее надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо![alt text][2]  [1]: http://www.cifra1.ru/general/upload/setting_support/Nastroika_VPN_v_Linux.rtf  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zubWT.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pptpsetup --create имя_сооединения --server IP_сервера --username login --password password
```

по вкусу

```
[--encrypt] [--start]
```

И не нужно изобретать велосипед,

Comment: 0 реакции. команда проходит, но в ifconfig'е только eth0 да lo. Или надо дать ещё какую-то команду?

Comment: попробовать после pptpsetup --create имя_сооединения --server IP_сервера --username login --password password запустить pppd call имя_ссоединениявсе команды через sudo, и да проверить для начала ping IP_сервера

Comment: Спасибо. Всё оказалось по-гениальному просто - не работала интернетовская розетка

Comment: ping рулит :-)